# Express.js not displaying images added dynamically to my webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express

I am trying to develop a simple app using node.js and express.js that works as follows. Attaching the screen shot of my app for reference

[image]

The user basically enters a location in his computer where image files are stored and then I dynamically generate the HTML file that displays those images as thumbnails. I am almost done except that Express is not serving my images and they appear as empty square boxes. Need help in trying to address this.

Before people mark this question as duplicate I would like to point out that this is not static web content where I can use the static middleware to sort this out. The user can input any directory on his computer and if there are any image files present then I need to display them.

EDIT:
This is how the standalone HTML page looks like. There are no problems with respect to paths in `img`

[image]

Comment: maybe problem with path or is there any error in console?

Comment: @yjs Nope. When I access the standalone generated HTML page it gets displayed without any issues

Comment: What is current inspect element in error page?

Comment: @yjs It says not allowed to load local resource. How should I handle this?

Comment: Can you put up the code where you are trying to read the files from the local resource/folder?

Comment: @rgk Just a try: var currURL = "file:\\C:\images\tiger.jpeg"; currURL = $(currURL).replace("file:\\",""); currURL = $(currURL).replace("\","/");

Comment: just before putting urls to img src's: if you can post a fiddle that would help

Comment: @yjs I was thinking on how to share the code. I forgot there was jsfiddle. Thanks. Will do that now and share the link

Comment: @yjs Here you go - The link which contains my node.js code and the generated HTML code - https://jsfiddle.net/ny2qvqe8/

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn Please look at this link - https://jsfiddle.net/ny2qvqe8/

Comment: @rgk Update external resources in fiddle????

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening standalone html in the browser, the protocol of the opened page is `FILE`. When you run a server on your localhost, the protocol is `http` or `https`. Modern browsers, do not allow to cross from the `http` protocol to the `file` protocol, that is why you are getting error:

> Not allowed to load local resource

I can suggest you to create a buffer directory under the server directory root, and copy all the images from the desired folder there. That will allow you to show the images without any restrictions.